# How to fill SQLITE before building APP?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-studio

Hi i'm making a simple Android APP, which only displays data from Database depending on current time. There are a lot of tutorials how to fill DB through inputs in emulator, but how can i fill the DB before building the APP in Android studio?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513084/how-to-ship-an-android-application-with-a-database